# Is there any Android mail app that notfies about new emails in subfolders (IMAP)?

Tags: android, email

#### Problem

I'm using mail filters in Thunderbird that move emails to specific mail folders (IMAP). After filters have been applied and unread messages have been moved to the folders, I open my Android e-mail app (e.g. Bluemail), it synchronizes, but it doesn't show that there are new e-mails that are located in subfolders. Only after I opened the folder directly I see the "new email" counter next to the folder name.

#### Question

Is there any mail app for android that notifies about new, unread e-mails in subfolders from IMAP?

#### What I tried so far

- BlueMail: support only for Exchange accounts, I contacted the developer. Perhaps it'll be implemented in the future)
- Samsung Mail: the new email counter on subfolders increases only after direct synchronization
- FairEmail: it synchronizes subfolders, but it's quite user-unfriendly

Comment: IMAP push only works for one folder so IMAP clients do not automatically check for mails in all IMAP folders. You usually have to configure mail checking for each folder you want to monitor. Not sure which Android mail apps support this.

Comment: Try FairEmail, I am pretty sure it's possible (can't confirm since I don't use Thunderbird). If it isn't, ask the developer.. Extremely cooperative//https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-5-0-fairemail-fully-featured-open-source-privacy-oriented-email-app.3824168/

Comment: In FairEmail app, long press the specific folder (s) which get populated based on rules and enable *notify on new messages*

Comment: @beeshyams thank you for the recommendation. FairEmail works so far, but it isn't as user-friendly as other e-mail clients. I think I'll continue looking for a solution

Comment: I have been through many of them and settled for **fairmail**. Yes, its a mission to set things up as the mind behind the design is weird. But looking at help invariably shows the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's E-Mail app (at least since 6.1.73.1) supports synchronisation per folder and subfolder. Go to `Settings -> SomeAccount -> "Folders to sync"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).